# Automatically display the numeric keyboard during a phone call

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, phone-call

I'm working on a Phonegap application for several platforms.

The application needs to make a phone call what is done in Javascript as follows:

```
document.location.href = 'tel:0111111111';
```

This one works fine on iPhone and when the call is hanged up, my application is well retrieving  the focus as expected.

However, during the phone call, the user must answer to a vocal message from a SVI by touching  the star key of the iPhone's numerical keyboard. In order to help the users I would like the numerical keyboard to be automatically displayed during the phone call without the user needs to display it explicitly.

Is it possible to have this control level?

Comment: If the numeric keyboard is created from scratch you can use input type="tel"

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not talking about this type of keyboard. I'm looking for displaying the keyboard available during a phone call and the user usually displays by touching the keyboard button between both Mute and Speaker buttons.